# Как сделать так, чтобы запрос не останавливался при переходе на другой Activity

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что я в `Activity` `SplashScreen` делаю запрос на сервер, для того чтобы получить цифры в ответ. В `SplashScreen` есть таймер 3 секунды и переходит на `MainActivity`, а сам завершается. И если с сервера пришел(успел за 3 сек) ответ, то на `DrawerItem` вставляется эта цифра, а иначе запрос на сервер делается заново в `MainActivity`. И я уверен что это очень неправильно.

**Вопрос**: Как правильно делать запрос на фоне всего один раз и при этом переходы по `Activity` не остановили его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите ваш запрос в intentservice или в service. Это самое простое и логичное решение

Comment: Ок, еще один вопросик. У меня везде, на всех `Activity` есть запросы, и если не дождавшись ответа от сервера перехожу на другой `Activity`, то крэшится, правильно! Так вот все запросы лучше вынести в Сервисы?

Comment: Если по выполнению запроса вам не нужно делать какие-либо действия на данной активити то можно вынести в сервис. А если надо то нет. Вам можно посмотреть библиотеку retrofit2, volley

Comment: так мне то и нужно чтобы после получения ответа от сервера обновился список.

Comment: Ну если от сервера ответ не придет при переходе на другую активити, то запрос нужно остановить. Или же можно данные которые отображаются в списке записывать в базу данных, а уже при открытии экрана брать их от туда

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!